# Postgres 8.4 creates a function that calls non-existing function

Tags: database, postgresql

I had succeeded to create the following function in PG 8.4.x

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS VOID
AS $function$
BEGIN
    select concat('a','b');
END;$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function is created without any errors 
But when I try to use the function I got :

```
select foo();
ERROR:  function concat(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select concat('a','b')             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  select concat('a','b')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "foo" line 2 at SQL statement
```

How comes that PG succeed to create a function that actually calls an unknown function? (CONCAT is supported only in PG 9.x)

Comment: I do not need to say that Postgres 8.4 has reached it's end-of-life a long time ago?

Comment: You should really upgrade to a supported Postgres version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because functions get compiled the first time you call them. Else it would not be possible to define a set of recursive functions where one calls the other :).

EDIT (thanks to Nick Barnes): Somewhat unrelated to the question there is a switch

```
SET check_function_bodies = true;
```

but this only enables basic syntax checks for PL/pgSQL functions. The binding will be done on first call nonetheless. Postgres will only attempt to resolve function / table names for LANGUAGE sql.

Comment: The example in question still works with `check_function_bodies` on. PL/pgSQL functions only receive basic syntax checking. Postgres will only attempt to resolve function / table names for `LANGUAGE sql`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

The PLpgSQL checks only syntax of embedded SQL in validation time. The semantic - identifiers, functions, ... is checked immediately before first evaluation in run-time. You can search *plpgsql_check* extension. It does complete check of embedded SQL.